# ACPI PCC probe failed / Busybox

Tags: boot, kernel, acpi, busybox

Until a few days ago I used the Elementary OS perfectly. But then began to show an error message when the system starts:

> ACPI PCC probe failed

This did not affect anything. Only appeared at the beginning. After researching I realized that this could be related to the kernel 3:19 that was giving some problems.

I found some solutions and hoped to solve the problem when I had some free time but today when I got home my computer had a new problem:

> ACPI PCC probe failed.
>
> Busybox v1.21.1 (ubuntu 1: 1.21.0-1.ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
>
> Enter help for a list of built-in commands.
>
> (inframfs)

The last thing I remember having made was an automatic update.

I do not have dual boot. And I really wanted to continue to use the elementary and not lose all my stuff.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The kernel message "ACPI PCC probe failed." comes from the ACPI Platform Communication Channel driver when it can't find a PCC mailbox during the PCC probing initialisation phase.  It is generally is not a fatal error and very likely has nothing to do with your failed boot.  It is most probably the last kernel message you see before your system failed to boot and nothing to do with the root cause.

0
down vote

I've filed a bug for this with an upstream fix to turn this error message into a debug message, this will hopefully land in the next kernel SRU release cycle

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1524930